# What is the difference between 突然 and 忽然?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, vocabulary, difference

They both have the meaning `sudden`, but what is a subtle difference between 突然 and 忽然?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are identical when used as an Adverb.

> 天空突然/忽然下起了大雨。

But 突然 can also be used as a complement of a verb.

> 这雨下得太突然了。

Where you can only use 突然。

Answer (score 0):

突然 忽然 exactly the same. 忽然 is more for writing.